# LinearLayout layout_weight

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I have a ListView that is populated with rows. These rows come from an XML file that looks like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="8dip"
android:weightSum="100">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/columnA"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>  
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/columnB" 
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/icon" 
    android:id="@+id/columnC"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >
</ImageView>       
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/columnD"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

The problem is that I want the columnC item and columnB item to be very close together, so that my rows are equally spaced out in three parts, i.e.: columnA, (columnB+columnC) and then columnD.  I tried to achieve this by using layout_weight as you can see, however the above code seems to have the opposite effect. columnA and columnB are very squished on the left, column C seems to be floating in a large space on its own, and then columnD is located close to columnC, with too much space on its right. What am I doing wrong? :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that you want columnC and columnB to have the same weight, but you have it set with them different.

Try

columnA:weight=2

columnB:weight=1

columnC:weight=1

columnD:weight=2

I have very limited experience with the weight attribute but I think this is how you can get your desired result.

If you're still having trouble with it, may help us help you if you can post a screen shot of how it looks, and how you want it to look.

Comment: Beat me to it, didn't realize by how much too... didn't get the "Load 1 new answer" till just a moment before I posted.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, this definately looks better, however columnD is still appearing too close to columnC, with too much space on the right :s May be something to do with the fact that its a checkbox.

Comment: okay - turns out I had to wrap my checkbox in a linearlayout to fix this remaining problem, and then set the weight and gravity in the linear layout. Thx!

Comment: You could also just use layout_marginLeft on the checkbox to move it over to the right a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try. You can basically figure how much space each view will "want" by weight/total weight. You don't have to try to make them equal 100.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="8dip"
    android:weightSum="100">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/columnA"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>  
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/columnB" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/icon" 
    android:id="@+id/columnC"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >
</ImageView>       
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/columnD"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```